# Exception while trying to consume a JMS Topic message using Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-camel, activemq-classic, jms-topic

I am trying to consume message from ActiveMQ Topic. Below is the Code:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJms
public class Config {

@Value("${activemq.broker-url}")
private String brokerURL;

@Bean
public ActiveMQConnectionFactory activeMQConnectionFactory() {
    ActiveMQConnectionFactory activeMQConnectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory();
    activeMQConnectionFactory.setBrokerURL(brokerURL);
    activeMQConnectionFactory.setTrustAllPackages(true);
    return activeMQConnectionFactory;
}

public DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory jmsListenerContainerFactory(){
    DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory defaultJmsListenerContainerFactory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
    defaultJmsListenerContainerFactory.setConnectionFactory(activeMQConnectionFactory());
    defaultJmsListenerContainerFactory.setPubSubDomain(true);
    return defaultJmsListenerContainerFactory;
}
```

My Consumer Code:

```
@Component
@EnableJms
public class Consumer {

   @JmsListener(destination = "xml.inbound.topic", containerFactory = "jmsListenerContainerFactory")
   public void Processor(final Message xmlMessage) {

   }
}
```

The Exception which I am getting is:

*Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'jmsTemplate'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jmsTemplate' defined in class path resource [com/investmentbank/equityfeedsprocessingrevised/config/Config.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate]: Factory method 'jmsTemplate' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.springframework.jms.config.DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory cannot be cast to class javax.jms.ConnectionFactory (org.springframework.jms.config.DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory and javax.jms.ConnectionFactory are in unnamed module of loader 'app')*

What am I doing wrong here ? Why the exception?

I have also tried :

```
@Bean
public DefaultMessageListenerContainer jmsListenerContainerFactory() {
        DefaultMessageListenerContainer dmlc = new DefaultMessageListenerContainer();
        dmlc.setConnectionFactory(activeMQConnectionFactory());
        dmlc.setPubSubDomain(true);
        return dmlc;
}
```

The Exception which I get here is:

*Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'jmsTemplate'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jmsTemplate' defined in class path resource [com/investmentbank/equityfeedsprocessingrevised/config/Config.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate]: Factory method 'jmsTemplate' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jmsListenerContainerFactory' defined in class path resource [com/investmentbank/equityfeedsprocessingrevised/config/Config.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property 'destination' or 'destinationName' is required*

Just to add my JmsTemplate code looks like this:

```
@Bean
public JmsTemplate jmsTemplate() {
JmsTemplate jmsTemplate = new JmsTemplate();
         jmsTemplate.setConnectionFactory(activeMQConnectionFactory());
         jmsTemplate.setPubSubDomain(true);
         return jmsTemplate;
}
```

I have implemented the JMS Topic Publisher using Apache Camel (Code):

```
ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("tcp://localhost:61616");
        CamelContext _ctx = new DefaultCamelContext(); 
        _ctx.addComponent("jms", JmsComponent.jmsComponentAutoAcknowledge(connectionFactory));
        _ctx.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {

            public void configure() throws Exception {
                from("file:src/main/resources?fileName=data-sample_2.csv")
                .process(new MyTransformRevised1())
                .to("file:src/main/resources/?fileName=emp.xml")                
                .split(body().tokenizeXML("equityFeeds", null)).streaming().to("jms:topic:xml.inbound.topic");
            }

        });
```

I am able to see the number of messages in "Message Enqueued" column of my Topic name.

What is going wrong ? I have read various posts on net but not able to solve the issue. Kindly help in resolving the issue. I am not able to read the message on ActiveMQ Topic. Let me know if some information is missing from my end.

Answer (score 2):

you could try to wrap the `activeMQConnectionFactory` in a `CachingConnectionFactory` and utilize the `DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer` to configure the `JmsListenerContainerFactory`:

```
@Bean
ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
    return new CachingConnectionFactory(activeMQConnectionFactory());
}

@Bean
public JmsListenerContainerFactory<?> jmsListenerContainerFactory(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
                                    DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer) {

    DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
    configurer.configure(factory, connectionFactory);
    return factory;
}
```

EDIT start:

could you try changing the `JmsTemplate` to:

```
@Bean
public JmsTemplate jmsTemplate(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
JmsTemplate jmsTemplate = new JmsTemplate();
         jmsTemplate.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
         jmsTemplate.setPubSubDomain(true);
         return jmsTemplate;
}
```

Comment: Just tried the above. I just added one more line to the above code, namely,  `factory.setPubSubDomain(true);` tried both ways before as well as after `configurer.configure(factory, connectionFactory);` but still didn't work. No Exception but no output as well. It's not ready to listen to the Topic somehow. I am really out of my mind as to how should I solve this.

Comment: how does the code look like where you send the messages to the topic? and could you try removing the `ConnectinFactory` bean as spring boot should already do that for you?

Comment: I have implemented JMS Publisher using Apache Camel. Have edited my question above to add the code for the same. I want to add additionally that when I was working with queue that was working perfectly fine but with Topic nothing works.

Comment: is there any change if you use the `jmsTemplate` to send a Message to the topic directly?

Comment: have not tried that. As mentioned above I have implemented my Publisher using Apache Camel and its sending the message to the ApacheMQ successfully as per the "Message Enqueued" number besides my Topic Name in ActiveMQ. Also, Apache Camel worked perfectly well with Queues and my JmsConsumer also worked perfectly fine with Apache Camel as "Publisher" and my JmsListener as "Consumer". So I don't think that Apache Camel as "Publisher" should be an issue here.

Comment: tried changes to JmsTemplate as well but still no Result. Nothing is printed. No Exception but No Output as well. It's refusing to listen to the Topic entirely. Don't understand as to what is the issue.

Comment: the same code is working with queues if you omit setting the pubsubdomain on jmstemplate and listenerfactory?

Comment: if you connect to your running application via jmx using jconsole or jmc and go to MBeans and then `org.apache.activemq` -> Broker -> localhost -> Topic -> xml.inbound.topic -> Attributes -> ConsumerCount. how many consumers do you have?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this with the below Code:

```
    public DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory jmsListenerContainerFactory(){
    DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory defaultJmsListenerContainerFactory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
                defaultJmsListenerContainerFactory.setConnectionFactory(activeMQConnectionFactory());
defaultJmsListenerContainerFactory.setPubSubDomain(true);
return defaultJmsListenerContainerFactory;
        }

     @Bean
     public JmsTemplate jmsTemplate() {
        JmsTemplate jmsTemplate = new JmsTemplate();
        jmsTemplate.setConnectionFactory(activeMQConnectionFactory());
        jmsTemplate.setPubSubDomain(true);
        return jmsTemplate;
    }

    @JmsListener(destination = "${my.inboundTopicName}", containerFactory = "jmsListenerContainerFactory")
    public void myProcessor(final Message xmlMessage) {
    ///

    }
```

I want to add that I am experiencing some unusual behavior.

1. At the time when the messages are generated from the producer and if
   the consumer is up then only the messages are consumed by the
   consumer. I mean that if the messages are produced by the producer
   and enqueued by ActiveMQ and after some time I turn on the consumer
   then the messages are not consumed by the consumer.
2. . Also it takes a while before the messages are consumed by the
   consumer.